# Get longitude and latitude from a shapefile with Leaflet in R

Tags: r, leaflet, mapping, centroids

I've been trying to map with `leaflet` to add `addCircles()` but my shapefile doesn't seem to have the latitude `lat` and longitude `lng` parameters so I got the centroids for each city as is the code below but it doesn't seem to show me the centroid points so I put in a df these values but I can't automate to get the points for n cities.

The data is [here](https://mega.nz/folder/Zg5RGYSB#zE68WEyAYFxnhDGpY4IfXw).

```
library(stringr)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
quito = st_read("C:/Users/crist/Downloads/Administraciones Zonales/Administración_Zonal.shp") %>% 
  st_simplify(dTolerance = 1000) %>% 
  sf::st_transform('+init=epsg:4326')

sectores = read.csv("C:/Users/crist/Downloads/sector.csv", header = T,sep = ";", dec = ",", row.names = 1)
sectores

full_data = inner_join(quito, sectores, by = 'NOMBRE') %>%
  mutate(label_map = sprintf("<strong>%s </strong><br/>Valor: %g<br/>",NOMBRE, TARIFA_PROMEDIO_POR_HAB_DISPONIBLE_...) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML))

bins = c(0, 10, 50, 100, 150,250)
pal_quito <- colorBin("Oranges", domain = full_data$TARIFA_PROMEDIO_POR_HAB_OCUPADA_..., 
                      bins = bins)

#I tried to do this because my shp didn't have the longitude and latitude variables 

full_data$centroids <- st_transform(full_data, 29101) %>% 
  st_centroid() %>% 
  st_geometry()

lngt_q = c(-78.41782, -78.67333, -78.4823, -78.60407, -78.36822, -78.50851, -78.56278, -78.3023)
lat_q = c(-0.08668143, -0.2179538, -0.1585809, 0.09029626, -0.4124271, -0.2112893, -0.311081, -0.2025039)

full_data$lngt_q =lngt_q
full_data$lat_q =lat_q

leaflet(data = full_data) %>%
  addTiles() %>% 
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
  addPolygons(data = full_data,
              color = "#444444", 
              weight = 1,
              smoothFactor = 0.5, 
              fillOpacity = 0.2,
              label = full_data$label_map, 
              fillColor = pal_quito(full_data$TARIFA_PROMEDIO_POR_HAB_OCUPADA_...),
              stroke = T,
              highlightOptions = highlightOptions(
                weight = 5,
                color = "#666666",
                fillOpacity = 0.7)) %>% 
  addCircles(full_data$centroids, lng = lngt_q, lat = lat_q, color = "#045a8d", weight = 1, radius =1500,
             fillOpacity = 0.2)
```

**[updated]**
There's a way to get the longitude and latitude of my shapefile automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61371842/11570343

```
library(stringr)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(mapview)  # I believe this is needed to make code above function

quito = st_read("C:/Users/Brian/Downloads/Administraciones Zonales/Administración_Zonal.shp") %>% 
      st_simplify(dTolerance = 1000) %>%
      #logintud y latitud   # this produced an error, thin it is intended as comment
      sf::st_transform('+init=epsg:4326')

## Adding the centroid of each polygon as a separate geometry column. This will not be active but can be accessed as needed
quito$geom2 = st_centroid(quito)
```